# How to make windows recognize my app as a firewall product?

Tags: delphi, firewall

I am developing a basic firewall and i want to set windows to recognize it as a firewall to stop displaying those messages eg (your computer doesn't have a firewall) ... how can i do that do i need a signature from microsoft ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you need is your Firewall is recognized by the `Windows Security Center`. Microsoft distributes guidance about how applications from ISVs can report status to Windows Security Center under a nondisclosure agreement (NDA). To request details about how to participate in this ISV program, you must send an mail to wscisv@microsoft.com.

Read these articles for more info about this topic

- [Implementing the Teredo Security Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Upcoming Action Center Changes for Security Vendor Software](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/windowssecurity/archive/2009/05/06/upcoming-action-center-changes-for-security-vendor-software.aspx)
- [Windows Firewall Categories and User Facing Impact](http://www.codenamewindows.com/?p=549)