# C# Windows Security Center Settings

Tags: c#, security, api, interface, center

I would like to disable the Action Center messages in Windows. I know where the registry holds the values for these checks but those are machine specific. And I know that I can disable the complete service. But I do not want to disable the service, I only want to not show the notifications/alerts/messages.

To see these options I am talking about goto: cmd.exe -> RunDll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL wscui.cpl

The security center will be started and click on the left on "Change Action Center settings".

Now I have referenced "C:\Windows\System32\wscui.cpl" in my C# project and added

```
using SecurityCenterAdmin;
```

I see I can create this object

```
SecurityCenterAdmin.WscAdmin admin = new WscAdmin();
admin.DoModalSecurityAction();
```

But I can find no references about it. Searching on Google for "WscAdmin msdn" or "SecurityCenterAdmin" yields no results.

Any hints?

Thanks in advance.
Mike

Comment: None of the answers led me to some dark 'Undocumented Windows' style resource about the `SecurityCenterAdmin` object that is referencable in .Net. As both answers given are helpful to accomplish what is needed, the most direct solution is that of LastCoder. But the most legitamate way might be given by Constantin Carapencea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're unwilling to go through the proper channels to get access to the API (wscisv@microsoft.com). You can always try robot-ting the process.

- Use Process.Start to open the action center, you seem to already have the command line "RunDll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL wscui.cpl".
- Use the FindWindow and FindWindowEx API functions to get window and control handles. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx You'll want to make use of the "Microsoft SPY++" Windows SDK tool for getting class names etc.
- Use the SendMessage API to simulate mouse messages to the window/controls http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_LBUTTONUP, WM_MOUSEMOVE etc etc. Using SPY++ will also help with this process.

If you're doing this without properly notifying the user then your software is pretty shady - maleware. I could see practical uses, as an internal program your company may use to quickly configure stand alone desktops or something, but it's really a stretch.

Comment: Yes using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.aspx and Toggle control patterns it is possible to uncheck the boxes and invoke the OK button. As I did that also for the page file settings I can do it to for this window. Although this does not answer my curiosity for `SecurityCenterAdmin.WscAdmin` I give you some credit anyway! And yes, I use this to configure a Windows tablet that is integrated into an industrial device.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior you describe is consistent with actions malware might take, therefore the system should be actively prohibiting this.

It seems that a private API exists for interacting with the Windows Security Center. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050095/how-to-make-windows-recognize-my-app-as-a-firewall-product), this interface is subject to NDA and could be obtained by contacting Microsoft (see details in the answer to the mentioned post) if your application has legitimate requirements for it.

There is also a public API for querying the WSC: [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg537273%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Windows-Security-Center-e4bcb429/view/SourceCode#content).

Comment: Thanks for the information, but that does not actually do the job. I still can not change the settings, only query them. I did find that before. What I was hoping to get more information about is the so it seems undocumented SecurityCenterAdmin interface that is found in C:\Windows\System32\wscui.cpl